# Tkinter grid manager cutting off buttons

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have the following layout:

```
    btnReset = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Reset", width = 12, command=self.__parent.reset)
    btnReset.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W", pady=5)
    btnRender = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Render", width = 9, command = self.render)
    btnRender.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)

    self.bScattered = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Backscattered", variable=self.plotType, value=1).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
    self.depolarized = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Depolarized", variable=self.plotType, value=2).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")

    self.rng = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Step").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")
    self.e = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame).grid(row=3,column=1)
    self.to = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="to").grid(row=3, column=2)
    self.e2 = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame).grid(row=3,column=3)
```

The problem is my third row looks like:

[image]

Instead of evenly spacing the 4 widgets I'm trying to place. How can I fix grid manager cutting off the last two and evenly space them on the screen?

EDIT: Here's a minimal example of my problem, running it should reproduce the results shown above

---

```
from Tkinter import Label, Toplevel, Frame, Button, IntVar, \
   BOTH, BOTTOM, Radiobutton, Entry, TOP, Tk

CHILDWIDTH      = 200
CHILDHEIGHT     = 325

class ToolsWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, root)
        self.__root = root
        self.plotType = IntVar()

        self.title("Tools")
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (CHILDWIDTH, CHILDHEIGHT,0, 0))
        #self.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ToolsWindow.ignore)
        self.container = Frame(self, background="red")
        self.container.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True )    

        self.coordinateFrame = Frame(self.container, background="green", width=50, height=50)
        self.coordinateFrame.config(highlightthickness=1)                        # create a small border around the frame
        self.coordinateFrame.config(highlightbackground="grey")
        self.coordinateFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=False)                                      

    @staticmethod
    def ignore():
        pass

    def setupToolBarButtons(self):
        self.upperButtonFrame = Frame(self.container, background="blue")                                  # upper button frame holding text buttons
        self.upperButtonFrame.pack(side=TOP)    

        btnReset = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Reset", width = 12, command=self.render)
        btnReset.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        btnRender = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Render", width = 9, command = self.render)
        btnRender.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.bScattered = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Backscattered", 
            variable=self.plotType, value=1).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.depolarized = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Depolarized", 
            variable=self.plotType, value=2).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")


        self.rng = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Step")
        self.rng.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.e = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame, width=8)
        self.e.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.to = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="to")
        self.to.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="w")
        self.e2 = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame, width=8)
        self.e2.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="w")

    def render(self):
        pass

root = Tk()
tool = ToolsWindow(root)
tool.setupToolBarButtons()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say "spacing the 4 widget", which 4 are you talking about? I see 6 in the screenshot, not counting the frame. And what do you consider the 3rd row? Is the row with "Rest" and "Render" the first row?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley thatd be because two of them are cut off. It should display `Step`TextBox `To` TextBox

Comment: Are you forcing the containing widget to a specific size? At some point tkinter has no choice but to chop widgets off -- it won't shrink them below a minimum size. Can you please provide a short and complete program we can run that shows chopped-off widgets? My guess is, there's a lot more code you aren't showing us that is causing the problem. Please don't post _all_ of your code. Instead, try to create a new program that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: I **am** forcing the widget to a certain size. Is there any way to make sure the frame adapts to that constant size so I can pack the grid without ´Step´ and the ´entry´ box being placed so far away?

Comment: There are plenty of solutions, but if you're forcing the frame to be too small, you're going to have to allow the frame to be bigger. Without knowing more about the layout it's impossible to give better advice. Tkinter won't shrink widgets below their natural size (unless you specifically request it), so you either need to make the widgets smaller or the container larger.

Comment: @BryanOakley I uploaded a minimal example if you wanted to take a look at it, I'm still stumped  :/

Comment: Why do you not just let tkinter decide the window, rather than forcing it to a specific size?

Comment: @BryanOakley well, if I comment out the geometry call line It doesn't help me , there is still way to much space between `step` and the `entry` box in column `1`. It'll resize the window naturally but the 3 row is still screwed up. EDIT, it seems to be creating some sort of pad between those first two boxes, which is **way** too much

Answer (score 0):

The slightly modified program posted below renders properly, so it must be something in the code you did not post that is causing the problem.  Are you limiting the size of the root window's, geometry anywhere?  I do not know what you mean by "evenly spaced" but you can use the width parameter on most widgets to increase the size.

```
from Tkinter import *

class TestIt(object):
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.upperButtonFrame=top
        btnReset = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Reset", width = 12)
        btnReset.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W", pady=5)
        btnRender = Button(self.upperButtonFrame, text = "Render", width = 9)
        btnRender.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)

        self.bScattered = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Backscattered").grid(row=1, column=0
        self.depolarized = Radiobutton(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Depolarized").grid(row=2, column=0,

        self.rng = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="Step").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.e = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame).grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.to = Label(self.upperButtonFrame, text="to").grid(row=3,   column=2, sticky="e")
        self.e2 = Entry(self.upperButtonFrame).grid(row=3,column=3)

top = Tk()
TI=TestIt(top)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I uploaded a minimal example to show my problem , see anything wrong with it?